# Do Methycobalamin Oral Supplements help raise B12 levels?

Tags: b12

[NutritionFacts.org](https://nutritionfacts.org/topics/b12/) says "...there is insufficient evidence to support the efficacy of the other forms of B, like methylcobalamin."

I currently take 500 mcg Methycobalamin oral supplements every alternate day. So I want to know whether they are helping raise/balance B12 levels of my body or not.

I will get my blood test done in a few days, but I want to know it as soon as possible, which is why I asked this question.
Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it does. I believe the amount you take is rather low, as it's not absorbed as good as cyanocobalamin